# How to compile multiple pages into one document

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5

I'm creating birthday postcards, each page of my document has a 4.5 x 6 margin and I've created six different pages. Now I would like to compile these on to a 13 x 19 page and be able to cut them equally. How can I compile these?

Answer (score 1):

Export the existing 4.5x6 InDesign document as a multi-page, high resolution, PDF.

Open a new 13x19" InDesign file and `File > Place` each page of the PDF you exported.

You can then arrange the pdf page imports however you would like.

When output the PDF data of the placed images will be output.